# Python date format D M d H:i:s T Y

Tags: python, date

I have a datetime object,

```
import time, datetime, pytz
current_unixtime                            = time.time()
current_date_milis_for_blibli               = int(round(current_unixtime * 1000))
current_datetime_object                     = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(current_unixtime, pytz.timezone('Asia/Jakarta'))
```

how do i convert it into:

```
 Mon May 16 14:07:15 WIB 2016
```

or in PHP equivalence:

```
D M d H:i:s T Y
```

What i tried are written below, as you can see, i can't seem to get the 3 characters for Day and Month:

```
year    = current_datetime_object.year
month   = current_datetime_object.month
day     = current_datetime_object.day
hour    = current_datetime_object.hour
minute  = current_datetime_object.minute
second  = current_datetime_object.second
```

Comment: Have you searched for relevant information or made any attempt to find an answer yourself?

Comment: i can just use an array filled with values of months, but i wanted a better solution. And i don't know how to get the "Mon" equivalent in python.

Comment: Well... okay, I guess that qualifies as trying _something_, but it's kind of the bare minimum. I mean, actually go out and look for how to turn a Python datetime into a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
result = current_datetime_object.strftime("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y")
```

You can also specify output by changing values in brackets.

Examples are based on datetime.datetime(2013, 9, 30, 7, 6, 5).

```
Code    Example    Meaning

%a      Mon                          # Weekday as locale’s abbreviated name.
%A      Monday                       # Weekday as locale’s full name.
%w      1                            # Weekday as a decimal number, where 0 is Sunday and 6 is Saturday.
%d      30                           # Day of the month as a zero-padded decimal number.
%-d     30                           # Day of the month as a decimal number. (Platform specific)
%b      Sep                          # Month as locale’s abbreviated name.
%B      September                    # Month as locale’s full name.
%m      9                            # Month as a zero-padded decimal number.
%-m     9                            # Month as a decimal number. (Platform specific)
%y      13                           # Year without century as a zero-padded decimal number.
%Y      2013                         # Year with century as a decimal number.
%H      7                            # Hour (24-hour clock) as a zero-padded decimal number.
%-H     7                            # Hour (24-hour clock) as a decimal number. (Platform specific)
%I      7                            # Hour (12-hour clock) as a zero-padded decimal number.
%-I     7                            # Hour (12-hour clock) as a decimal number. (Platform specific)
%p      AM                           # Locale’s equivalent of either AM or PM.
%M      6                            # Minute as a zero-padded decimal number.
%-M     6                            # Minute as a decimal number. (Platform specific)
%S      5                            # Second as a zero-padded decimal number.
%-S     5                            # Second as a decimal number. (Platform specific)
%f      0                            # Microsecond as a decimal number, zero-padded on the left.
%z                                   # UTC offset in the form +HHMM or -HHMM (empty string if the the object is naive).
%Z                                   # Time zone name (empty string if the object is naive).
%j      273                          # Day of the year as a zero-padded decimal number.
%-j     273                          # Day of the year as a decimal number. (Platform specific)
%U      39                           # Week number of the year (Sunday as the first day of the week) as a zero padded decimal number. All days in a new year preceding the first Sunday are considered to be in week 0.
%W      39                           # Week number of the year (Monday as the first day of the week) as a decimal number. All days in a new year preceding the first Monday are considered to be in week 0.
%c      Mon Sep 30 07:06:05 2013     # Locale’s appropriate date and time representation.
%x      09/30/13                     # Locale’s appropriate date representation.
%X      07:06:05                     # Locale’s appropriate time representation.
%%      %                            # A literal '%' character.
```

Example is taken from [here](http://strftime.org/)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module:

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%a %B %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y')
```

Comment: @RaymondSeger: Sure thing. I couldn't tell from your question, but you may want to use `%b` (lowercase) as opposed to `%B` if you want a month's *abbreviated* name.

Comment: it's %b actually, because the PHP equivalent is "M"

Answer (score 1):

I can find the answer to the question here, turns out Python Documentation mentioned this kind of conversion between datetime object to a formatted string:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior